# MySQL CONVERT_TZ returns null

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, mysql-workbench

MySQL `CONVERT_TZ` returns `null`, if timezone value is in plus.

example:

```
select CONVERT_TZ(now(),SUBSTRING(timediff(now(),convert_tz(now(),@@session.time_zone,'+00:00')),1,5),'+00:00');
```

it returns perfect time `2015-12-16 10:32:19` when the time zone is in minus value. The same is not working when the time zone value is in plus. For an example `@@session.time_zone` returns `05:30`. If I `concat` plus manually, it is working. Please let me know, if any alternative solutions are available.

Manually concatenated code:

```
select CONVERT_TZ(now(),concat("+",SUBSTRING(timediff(now(),convert_tz(now(),@@session.time_zone,'+00:00')),1,5)),'+00:00');
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

When the difference is positive, the `SUBSTRING(timediff(now(),convert_tz(now(),@@session.time_zone,'+00:00')),1,5)` part returns a positive values, thats without the `+`.

But [CONVERT_TZ](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz) expects the offset to contain either `+` or `-`, so without it the value is not proper `offset` and the function returns `NULL` as specified.

Simply said - results of `timediff` are not proper timezone offsets.

You might use [DATE_ADD](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) instead, it allows for `-` too.

Comment: Thanks, Is there any other options to get proper timezone?

Comment: @Nisar I did not find any, but check the edited answer for an alternative.

Comment: Thanks again, Sorry! I already used this scenario which is creating some new issues using DATE_ADD and DATE_SUB.